# SQL presto - cross join unnest null value

Tags: sql, null, presto, unnest, trino

I have arrays of different sizes and I want each value in the array to be in separate rows.
To do that, I have used the cross join unnest. It is working however, it is deleting null array.

So, I have my column ID with the different arrays and some are nulls, when I do

```
select *
    from table 
    cross join unnest (t.id) as t(order_id)
    where length(order_id) = 5  or order_id is NULL
```

I only get the following results

| ID | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 23deo jfr32 6582w | 23deo |
| 23deo jfr32 6582w | jfr32 |
| 23deo jfr32 6582w | 6582w |

and I want

| ID | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 23deo jfr32 6582w | 23deo |
| 23deo jfr32 6582w | jfr32 |
| 23deo jfr32 6582w | 6582w |
| null | null |

If someone knows how to unnest null values it would be much appreciated. I've been looking on the internet and I saw that we could include a WITH ORDINALITY clause but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Use `LEFT JOIN UNNEST` instead of `CROSS JOIN UNNEST`.
Feature was added in [Presto 319](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/1522)

If you have previous version, then the workaround can be using subquery with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
with exploded as (
select *
    from table t
    cross join unnest (t.id) as t(order_id)
)

select t.*, e.order_id 
  from table t
       left join exploded e on t.join_key=e.join_key
```

Just use correct join key